# How to use sum function based on other columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb6

This is my table:

```
 SubjectCode   |  Unit | Instructor
   IS 26            3      James    
   IS 26            3      James
```

The result should be:

```
SubjectCode   |  Unit | Instructor
    IS 26         3       James
```

My code:

```
msql = "SELECT  Sum(Unit) AS Unit" & _
        " From classprogram " & _
        " WHERE Instructor= '" & cboInstructor.Text & "'and Semester='" & cboSemester.Text & "'" & _
        " GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(' ', Instructor, SubjectCode);"
```

I want the answer of that is 3.
How can I proceed further?

Comment: And what language are you using?  This looks like VB code.  In any case, what is the exact problem?

Comment: yes I use vb6.I want to sum unit base on subjectcode and instructor with distinct subjectcode also.when I try put two same subjectcode and the of its subjectcode is 3.But the answer is 6.Thanks for the reply

Comment: This sql does not work?

Comment: post your input and expected output

Comment: SubjectCode | Unit | Instructor
    IS 26      |    3  |  James 
    IS 26      |    3  |  James

Comment: I want the answer is 3 because it is the same subjectcode